# Infinite Ajax animation

Tags: jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/69eEL/808/

I want to create an animation that will constantly play while resources are being requested via ajax.

**Update**

For this question, I've simply got a div moving infinitely downwards to exemplify any infinite animation:

```
function start(change){    
    $('div').animate({
        top: speed_change
    }, 2, 'linear', start );

}

speed_change = '+=20px';
start();
```

Firstly, is there a better way to cause an infinite animation? **It seems a bit stupid to animate it for 20px/2ms only the animiate another 20px/2ms ad infinitum. Be cool to just set it off infinitely with one function call...**

Secondly, and onto the meat of the question, how can I smoothly stop the div from moving? So when the ajax has completed, how do I stop that box moving?

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'test.html',
  context: document.body
}).done(function() {
  function_to_stop_box_moving_down();
});
```

Notice I said **smoothly**. I don't want the box to suddenly stop. I want it to gradually begin slowing to a stop. If another ajax request is fired, I want the gradually slowing animation to speed up again.

Should I look into a library such as greensock for this?

http://jsfiddle.net/NK3pe/3/

Comment: To stop the moving div, you can use jQuery's .stop() method. To make it "Smooth", you can stop it then manually move it a few more pixels more slowly. I don't have any code for you, but that's one idea to try.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean. Is the infinite duration desired behavior, but you just want to stop the animation at a certain point?  Or do you see the potentially infinite duration as a negative side effect of your code?

Comment: Sorry, yeah the first one. Infinite is desired behaviour, but I want to stop it at a certain point (when ajax request has been completed)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at jQuery's `stop` method, [here](http://api.jquery.com/stop/). It can be used to stop an existing animation that is already going on. You could call this stop method as needed from an outside code.

**Update:** You could make it infinite by starting the animation once, with a destination `top` value equal to `delta * seconds` where `delta` would be the amount of height change every second, and `seconds` would be the amount of seconds the animation should take (you also need to parse this argument in as the actual duration of the animation).

Does that make sense?

Comment: Is that an answer the first part of my question? yeah, makes sense :) Would make the speed constant regardless of how slow the computer was

Answer (score 0):

Only just really started getting into it, but greensock seems to be the way to go here:

```
var trackMaster = new TimelineLite({ paused: true });

trackMaster.from( $('.slow'),   20, { left:'+=200' }, 0)
           .from( $('.medium'), 10, { left:'+=200' }, 0)
           .from( $('.fast'),    5, { left:'+=200' }, 0)

$('#restart').on('click', function(){
    console.log('restarting');
    trackMaster.restart();
});

$('#pause').on('click', function(){
    console.log('pause');
    trackMaster.pause();
});

$('#resume').on('click', function(){
    console.log('resume');
    trackMaster.resume();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NK3pe/16/